# copying files from one folder to another only if their file name is a in a specified text file c#

Tags: c#, arrays, file, copy

I need to copy files from one folder to another but only if their file name is also in a text file. The text file is set up like so

```
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg
etc
```

There are around one-million files to copy. I'm using C#.

What would the best way to go about this be? I'm not sure if I should first read all the file names from the text file and put them in to a list then possibly convert the list in to an array then maybe use the array somehow? Or maybe there's a better way to go about it?

I know how to read and write to files and how to copy from one source destination to another. I don't know how to filter out specific files when copying from one source destination to another though.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Read Text File Line by Line and then move them instead of reading all file at once.

Comment: 1 line 1 file name or 1 line total file name?

Comment: Perhaps read the text file into a list and then use list.find(filename) or list.exists(filename). I've done similar in python using a python list and os.walk(). Don't forget to upper or lower case all the searches and list elements.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What did you try, and did you find methods like File.ReadAllLines()? Do you know foreach?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will help you the process you want

```
        string source = @"C:\SourcePath\";
        string destination = @"C:\DestinationPath\";

        string[] strFiles = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Filename.txt").Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < strFiles.Length; i++)
        {
            File.Copy(source + strFiles[i], destination + strFiles[i]);
        }
```

Comment: wait disregard that, .Split('\r'); seems to work appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If the text file is one line with million files name. Use this

```
        string from = @"c:\from" , to =@"d:\to"; // source and destination
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"c:\list.txt"); // your files list
        string total=file.ReadLine();

        string[] tobecopied = total.Split(' ');
        foreach(string fil in tobecopied)
        {
            if(File.Exists(from+@"\"+fil))
               {
                File.Copy(from+@"\"+fil,to+@"\"+fil);
               }
            else
               {
                MessageBox.Show(fil+"Not found ");
               }
        }
```

But if the text file have 1 line per 1 file , for example

FIle1.exe

File2.exe

use this

```
        string from = @"c:\from" , to =@"d:\to"; // source and destination
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"c:\list.txt"); // your files list
        string total="";
        string temp="";
        while((temp=file.ReadLine())!=null)
        {
            total+=temp+" ";

        }
        string[] tobecopied = total.Split(' ');
        foreach(string fil in tobecopied)
        {
            if(File.Exists(from+@"\"+fil))
               {
                File.Copy(from+@"\"+fil,to+@"\"+fil);
               }
            else
               {
                MessageBox.Show(fil+"Not found ");
               }
        }
```

These ways also check for file existance.

Hope it works. If someone see error please edit it.

Comment: Hey your 2nd answer for splitting on seperate lines seems to split on a space instead?

Comment: Good answer though, I think both will work fine! Appreciate it. I would upvote if I had 15 reputation!

Comment: Would you happen to know how to do this but use robocopy to copy instead of windows copy?

Comment: I'm doing research about it and it's really confusing!! I'm only 15 ,bro. From my research, it's somehow faster. But **LOTS** mor confusing. Google "robocopy c#" and adapt some of them. Wish you luck.

Comment: @user3559010 If you read my code throughly , I add " " for each line and then seperate it with " ". So I got array that each contain 1 file name